# What are the operational limits of Rpy2?

Tags: python, rpy2

I know basic python programming and thus want to stay on the python datasci path.
Problem is, there are many R packages that appeal to me as a social science person.
Can Rpy2 allow full use of any general arbitrary r package, or is there a catch. How well does it work in practice?

If Rpy2 is too limited, I'd unfortunately have to branch over to r, but I would rather not, because of the extra overhead.

Thanks
Tai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring the presumed limitations on.

`Rpy2` is, at its lower level (the `rpy2.rinterface` level), exposing a very large part of the R C-API. Technically, one can do more with `rpy2` than one can from R itself (writing C extension for R would possibly be the only way to catch up). As an amusing fact,doing "R stuff" from `rpy2` can be faster than doing the same from R itself (see the `rpy2` documentation benchmarking the access of elements in an R vector).

The higher level in `rpy2` (`rpy2.robject` level) is adding a layer that makes "doing R stuff" more "pythonic" (although by surrendering the performance claim mentioned above). R packages look like Python modules, has classes such as Formula, Factor, etc... to have all R objects as Python classes, has a conversion system to let one complex R structures can be mapped to Python objects automagically (see example with `lme4` in the `rpy2` documentation0, translates on the fly invalid R variable names ('.' is a valid character for variable names in R), create on the fly Python docstrings from R documentation.

Comment: Wow thanks for that interesting info on Rpy. i was just scared off by all the Rpy2 SO questions.

So the amount of R I need to know to use the "object" level seems minimal. Is that correct? How well does it work?

Comment: "Questions on SO" might mean that people use `rpy2` (or at least try to for a little while). "Scary questions on SO" might mean that it is well documented and only the scary stuff makes to SO. It might also mean it is not well documented and/or anything is scary though. How well does it work ? Well, `pip install rpy2` and go through the introduction to `rpy2` in the documentation....

Comment: Ok. So there is no reason to think some random package might not fully "work" in the future... and is it a moot point because I would have to learn R fully anyway.  I believe from the answers herein, the former is a no and the latter is a yes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use RPy2 with IPythons [%rmagic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/rmagic.html).

However, RPy2 is not a replacement or port or R's library of statistical function to Python. It's basically a simple way to call R from within Python (an R interpreter is started in the background). You may pass basic data-structures between R and Python (numpy arrays etc.), but more specialized structures (R's zoo or xts objects for example) might cause problems.

In the end, you still need to know R's syntax etc. to use RPy2. It's nice to interact with the R-Objects in Python, but you still need to know a lot about the R-Objects.

Comment: Thanks. So in the end, I need to learn R anyway? What is the best resource for learning only those attributes of R that I need to use Rmagic? 

Will these limits of Rmagic cause real problems, or can they be circumvented?

Comment: I think there is no yes/no answer, because I don't know your data analysis task. But I'm pretty sure that RPy2 has been designed for more or less skilled R-Users, which know both languages (Python+R) quite well.

Comment: ERGMS (http://badhessian.org/2012/09/lessons-on-exponential-random-graph-modeling-from-greys-anatomy-hook-ups/)

Comment: When it comes to graphs, there is networkx or igraph for python. I don't think that R is needed here (i.e. the only possible solution)

Comment: Yes but ERGMS in particular has no implementation in python unfortunately, IIRC

Comment: @dorvak : As shocking as it might appear, rpy2 was not designed for skilled R users. Python users that want to "just use" anything implemented in R were very much at the center of many design decisions. Now that was the plan. Effectively, what happened was that a number of Python people turned out to often propose to reimplement whatever is needed in Python, while a number of users just decided to learn both Python and R. At least this is what I am making out the popularity of evaluating string as R code and binding data objects to symbols in the R "GlobalEnv" (instead of keeping it clean).